# Arrays as parameters and inputs in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Okay so I understand that a function cannot return an array but rather a pointer to an array but I had other questions.

Does the array that I am going to be pointing to need to be declared outside the function?

If I dynamically allocate memory for an array in this function, would I able to free it within a function that called this function?

Say intended to loop this function in a for loop would this be acceptable/ideal as long as I freed the memory before calling It again.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it would be easier and more efficient to allocate the array in the calling function and pass it as parameter to the other (resizing it if necessary), than creating and destroying tons of arrays in your for loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can return an array of a function if you know
that the memory exists further and you´re freeíng it if nessecary.

Rough possible cases:
A non-dynamic array outside of the function can be passed to it.
The function could return the same array (it makes no sense,
beauce the caller should have it alaready, but it is possible)

A non-dynamic array of a function can NOT be returned to the outside
because it will cease to exist at the end of the function.

A dynamic allocated array from anywhere can be passed/returned as much as you want,
as long you know when and where it will be free´d
(ie. don´t forget the free and don´t access it after the free)

Comment: In code like `static int ary[10]; return ary;` the compiler silently substitutes a pointer to the first element (type `int *`) for the actual array `ary` (type: `int [10]`). People sometimes say that the array "decays" to a pointer in this context (and many others including passing arrays *to* functions).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "You can return an array" isn't really true. You can write code that looks like it is returning an array to a newbie, but actually you are returning a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: "it makes no sense because the caller should have it already" - I tend to agree, although `fgets` does this :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Pointer thing: Of course. fgets: Can return NULL too, so it can be used for error-checking :) The only reason for a fix return would be more convenient code-writing in some cases ("nested" commands with the return value)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can free the dynamically allocated memory for the array from the calling function. it is fine provided you allocated memory on `heap` using function like `malloc()`. Then you can free that memory from any function if you have a pointer to that memory using `free()`.